# InstagramグラフAPIを使用して、インスタグラムの投稿内容を自社のサイトに表示する方法について

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Instagramで投稿した内容を、自社のサイトにも表示したいと考えています。

管理者や開発者のみのデータにアクセスする予定ため、アプリは開発者モードのままです。
グラフAPIエクスプローラで、ユーザーアクセストークンを取得する際に、
instagram_basicへのアクセス許可をリクエストすると、ログインレビューの申請が求められます。

ひとまず警告を無視してトークンを取得したのちに、InstagramビジネスアカウントIDを取得しようとすると、facebookページのIDのみが返ってくるようです。

> /{facebook_page_id}?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token={token}

開発者モードでも、アプリレビューをしないと
Instagramの情報へはアクセスできないということでしょうか？？
でも全ての情報にアクセスできないと、レビュー用のテスト版が作成できない気がします…。。
または、別に原因があるのでしょうか？

FacebookページとInstagramビジネスアカウントは連携済みです。
何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。